# Chartjs doesn't update dataset label on tooltips

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to show dataset labels on ChartJS tooltips. It works fine by setting:

```
Chart.defaults.global = {
    multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>"
}
```

. But when a label changes, it doesn't get updated on tooltips and the previous label is still shown:

```
myLineChart.datasets[0].label = 'new label';
myLineChart.update();
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of try like that, you just put your code *within chart options*. It will work fine.

example:

```
var radarOptions = {
  multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>"
}
var ctx = document.getElementById("radarChart").getContext("2d");//radarChart is the canvasid for radar chart//
var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Radar(radarData, radarOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

For tooltips try something like this:

```
myLineChart.data.labels = labels; //change all labels
myLineChart.update();
```

or

```
myLineChart.data.labels[0] = 'new label';
myLineChart.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

For VB.NET, make sure it's all built as a string.

```
var radarOptions = {
    multiTooltipTemplate: "<" + "%= datasetLabel %> - " + "<" + "%= value %>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2
I have initilized chartlabel on every click of graph display.
   `this.lineChartLabels=[];`
 I have put condition in div ,untill data comes to chartlabels ,do not render the graph

`<div *ngIf="lineChartLabels!=0">`
It works for me